# Внедрение вредоносного кода в исполняемые файлы

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Многие вирусы заражают другие исполняемые файлы путем внедрения в них вредоносного кода. Как они это делают?

Как получается, что зараженная программа продолжает работать и в то же время, видимо, в другой потоке, совершает нехорошие вещи? Возможно ли такое сделать средствами C#?

Answer (score 2):

Да, на C# можно такое делать. Вредоносный код должен прописывать себя в выполняемый файл по средствам [Reflection](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55710/Reflection-in-NET) и [Reflection Emit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121568/Dynamic-Type-Using-Reflection-Emit).

1. Заражаем кодом первый исполняемый файл (exe).
2. При запуске зараженного приложения должен запускаться "код", а потом медленно искать другие сборки .net на диске.
3. Прописывать себя в найденные, если они еще не заражены.

Заражение будет происходить только .net сборок ;)

Answer (score 2):

Классика файловых вирусов: добавляем секцию со своим кодом в конец файла, переносим точку входа на нее. В итоге выполняется левый код, который потом передает управление на оригинальную точку входа. Манипуляция файлами доступна и из .NET в том числе, так что можно и на нем написать, только не нужно.

Comment: Ибо создание вредоносного ПО карается законом.